# If numbers $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $20$ are arranged in a circle in any order, there must be three close numbers whose sum is at least $32$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We are required to use contradiction to prove that:

> If the numbers $1, 2, ..., 20$ are arranged in a circle regardless of order, that there must be $3$ close numbers whose sum is at least $32$.

If we list the numbers, say in a clockwise direction starting at any arbitrary number say, $k_1$ upto $k_{20}$ we look at the total sum as being

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  (k_1 + k_2 + k_3) + (k_2 + k_3 + k_4) + (k_3 + k_4 + k_5) + ... + (k_{19} + k_{20} + k_1) + (k_{20} + k_1 + k_2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Here, we realise that every number from 1 to 20 appears atleast 3 times in the above big sum. So the big sum is literally $3(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 20)$

We know however that the total sum of values from $1$ to $20$ can be achieved by using the formula
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} \\
         &= \frac{20(20 + 1)}{2} \\
         &= 210
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Right now am stuck at this point. How to prove that there will be $3$ numbers that have a sum lesser than $32$.

My thinking is that if i join up the three biggest numbers, namely $18 + 19 + 20$, I will end up with $57$. But then how do I prove it with contradiction in this induction question?

Comment: "at least 3 times" means the sum is,**at minimum** 3(1+\dots+20)$. But it is "exactly three times," so you can say it is equal to.

Comment: So, the sum of $1$ to $20$ is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k = 210$, so the total sum of the above $(k_1+k_2+k_3)+(k_2+k_3+k_4)+\dots+(k_{20}+k_1+k_2)$ is $630$.  The average value of each parenthetical expression is then $\frac{630}{20}$, or $31.5$.  Can you continue from there?

Comment: Also, "How to prove that there will be 3 numbers that have a sum lesser than 32?" is the wrong question. You want to show that there are 3 numbers that have a sum $\geq 32.$

Comment: As an aside, induction does not appear to be useful in any proof for this result.  This is a straightforward proof by contradiction and/or pigeonholing

Comment: Am having problem trying to understand the problem to solve it in a proof by induction manner, coz i realized where am heading is trying to make the problem harder than it seems

Comment: Induction is for establishing theorems of the form $\forall k \in \mathbb N \dots$.  This problem isn't like that, in fact, it is finite.  There are only $20!$ cases to check.  So the best thing for this type of problem is to try to build a counter example and see why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction is not useful in such kind of problem, as noticed by J. Moravitz to prove that let observe

$$\sum k_i = 210 \implies 3\frac{\sum k_i}{20}=31.5$$

therefore there exists some triple which sum is greater than that value.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by 'three close numbers' you mean a triplet of adjacent numbers in some permutation (following from what you gave in the details of your question).

I am not very sure about where you can use induction effectively here. But if you do look at the problem from a pigeonhole principle point of view, the answer is fairly straightforward and you're actually almost there, you're just looking at the wrong question. What you should try to prove is that there will always be a triplet where the sum is at least 32; of course there have to triplets where the sum is less than 32 as well.

Just notice that the sum you calculated, which equals $210$, appears exactly thrice when you take the sum across all triplets of interest; and there are exactly 20 of these in any rearrangement in a circle as you've already figured out. Then it follows immediately that 
$$\frac{3}{20}\sum_{i=1}^{20}i=31.5, $$ which implies that if the sums for all triplets of interest were less than 32, they would be at most 31, which gives a contradiction because the sums cannot match; it is strictly less in case this were true.